# Как узнать длину сжатого файла при помощи bat

Tags: bat, сжатие, winrar

Я создаю архив при помощи следующей команды:

```
rar a -s -m5 -mc0:0t+ 1.rar arch
```

В данной папке находится файл 1234.txt. Мне нужно создать bat-команду для того, чтобы узнать размер сжатого файла '1234.txt' в архиве '1.rar'.

Команда

```
rar v 1.rar
```

Выдает следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если делать разбивку на токены, то первому должно соответствовать Pathname/Comment, а третьему - нужный мне Packed. Но запрос

```
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%x in ('rar v 1.rar') do if "%%y"=="1234.txt" echo %%x
```

выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, кто-то знает, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Разность размеров архивов не равна размеру файла в архиве. Особенно для слитных архивов...

Comment: Используй `rar v archivename.rar | find "new_filename"`

Comment: Я согласна, что та разность, которая получается при последней команде не равна размеру файла в архиве. Но если рассматривать 'Свойства архива->Архив', то там есть информация об общем размере, размере в архиве и степень сжатия. И вот разность между параметрами двух архивов "размер в архиве" и равна размеру сжатого файла (проверено на нескольких архивах). Но каким запросом получить данный параметр я нигде не могу найти

Comment: *если рассматривать 'Свойства архива->Архив', то там есть информация об общем размере, размере в архиве и степень сжатия* Сведения об архиве и файлах в нём даёт команда `v`. См. выше. Подробнее - см. `rar /?`.

Comment: Я использовала данную команду, но там при добавлении | find "new_filename" отображается просто название директории и файла. А может быть Вы подскажете, как из результата, который выдает команда rar v archivename.rar,  вытащить значение в столбце 'packed' в отдельную переменную?

Comment: `@for /f "tokens=3,8" %x in ('rar v archive_name') do @if "%y"=="filename.ext" echo %x`

Comment: *вытащить значение в столбце 'packed' в отдельную переменную* Заменить echo на set.

Comment: Спасибо, я переделала данную команду, т.к. имя файла находится в первой подстроке, т.е. for /f "tokens=1,3" %%y in. Но почему-то в консоле при выполнении bat теперь это выводится так: if "название.txt" == "название.txt" echo = %x, следом идет строка: if 569 == "filename.ext" set zip = %x. Я посмотрела, 569 - это размер сжатого файла, т.е. из третьей колонки. Т.е. вместо %x 569 не подставляется, а как будто два раза вместо y и сравнивает почему-то это число с названием файла. И поэтому код не работает

Comment: Ни хрена не понял... Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте в него эту информацию - но с нормальным форматированием. Туда же добавьте полный вывод команды `rar v`, включая и саму команду (если файлов много - оставьте целевой и пару других, остальное удалите).

Comment: @Akina, добавила

Comment: Ну неужели Вы не видите, что имя файла отдаётся в одной строке, а сведения о файле - в другой? что, кстати, говорит о том, что у Вас версия весьма старенькая... я верстал команду на основе актуальной версии. Лучше обновите (достаточно обновить только сам RAR.EXE, выдрав его из актуального инсталлера). Ибо на текущей версии придётся вводить флаговую переменную, а это тот ещё геморрой...

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!